# MS Office plugin for full support of Wacom-Digitized Tablets

Tags: microsoft-office, plugins, microsoft-powerpoint, ink

**Background:** When using Microsoft OneNote with a "convertible tablet" (computer with Wacom-digitized screen and pen), you can draw "ink" with one side of the pen and then flip it over to erase (and the pen's button lets you lasso-select ink).  This feature is also found in Window's built-in support for tablets and you can also find it in third party programs like "PDF Annotator."  In PowerPoint, however, you can draw ink with the one end, but if you flip over to the eraser, it has the same action as the "pen side."

One workaround is to install a program given to me by the university I attend, called "PDF Annotator", and to use its "Print to PDF Annotator" feature to import PowerPoint slides into it.  However, this is very time consuming and not everyone has access to it.

**Question:** My question is whether or not there is any kind of plugin you can get for Microsoft Office (Powerpoint, mostly) to add advanced ink functionality (primarily the ability to erase with the built-in eraser) to MS Office products besides OneNote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but I discovered that it does let you erase if you're drawing in presentation mode (rather than edit mode).